# Footer works on xlsx exporting but not in Mpdf with Phpspreadsheet

Tags: php, pdf, header, footer, phpspreadsheet

Hi everyone and thanks in advance for your help.

I'm trying to set Footer to a pdf Phpsrpreadsheet generated file but, although it works when I export it in xlsx it doesn't work when I save it as a pdf (mpdf) file.

The code is something like:

```
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getHeaderFooter()->setOddFooter('SomeFooter');
```

I also tried:

```
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getPageMargins()->setBottom(1);
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getPageMargins()->setFooter(1);
```

Is there any solution or do I have to roughly create xslx and later convert it in pdf?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

No one answered. I solved with a function that:

- Finds the end of the page.
- creates a line at the end of each page.
- sets the height of that line
- reduces bottom margin of the same height (not exceeding minimum printable margins)
- Writes the footer

It's a rough workaround maybe, but that worked. Maybe someone knows a better way. Hope it helps for somebody